# Showing an Integer tableview in javaFx as a string

Tags: java, sql, javafx, tableview

I am trying to show a tableview where when the value in the table is a integer like 1 for example I want to display a String. So far I tried to get the cellValue like this:

```
public void changeView() {
        if(intervall.getCellFactory().call(intervall).equals(1)) {
            intervall.getCellFactory().call(intervall).setText("Täglich");
        }
    }
```

And I am calling the method in my initialize after setting the cellvalue.

```
public void initializeTable() {

        try {

            // Ablesen
            Statement pStatement = connection.createStatement();
            flightList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            ResultSet myRs = pStatement
                    .executeQuery("select * from fluglinie where fluggesellschaft =\"" + fluggesellschaft + "\"");
            while (myRs.next()) {
                flightList.add(new flightRouteAddModel(myRs.getString("startFlughafen"),
                        myRs.getString("zielFlughafen"), myRs.getString("startDatum"), myRs.getString("flugzeug"),
                        myRs.getInt("intervall"), myRs.getInt("anzahlEconomy"), myRs.getInt("anzahlBusiness"),
                        myRs.getFloat("preisEconomy"), myRs.getFloat("preisBusines"), myRs.getFloat("distanz")));

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        }


        startAirport.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("startAirport"));
        targetAirport.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("targetAirport"));
        flightDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("flightDate"));
        airplane.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("airPlane"));
        intervall.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("intervall"));
        seatCountEco.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("countEconomy"));
        seatCountBus.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("countBusiness"));
        priceEco.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("priceEconomy"));
        priceBus.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("priceBusiness"));
        distance.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("distance"));

        table.setItems(flightList);
        changeView();

    }
```

But it is not working can someone maybe take a look at this? I know changing the db would be maybe a better solution but I kinda wanted to try this workaround

Answer (score 2):

The `cellFactory` returns `TableCell`s. Calling this yourself does not result in a cell that is part of the `TableView` (or becomes part of it). Any `TableCell` with a properly impelemented `equals` method never yields `true`, if 1 (or any other `Integer`) is passed.

Assuming you always want to display `Täglich` instead of 1, the way to go about this is using a custom `cellFactory` for this column:

```
intervall.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<flightRouteAddModel, Integer>() {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
        String text = "";
        if (item != null) {
            switch(item) {
            case 1:
                text = "Täglich";
                break;
            case 7:
                text = "Wöchentlich";
                break;
            default:
                text = String.format("Alle %d Tage", item);
                break;
            }
        }
        setText(text);
    }

});
```

BTW: Please learn about the java naming conventions. This makes the code easier to read for other people and it should make this more readable even for yourself, since all java APIs (that I know of) use these conventions: Type names start with an uppercase letter.